# How to use TFS Build Process: LabelSources?

Tags: tfs, build-process

I'm attempting to modify my build process file for TFS 2010. I have a flag that is set when queuing the build, and when said flag is set, I want to create a Label, and add all the source files in the compiled project to that label.

On sequential builds, with the flag set, I than want to replace older source files in said label with anything new in the changeset being compiled.

I've been attempting to do this with LabelSources with no luck, and there is but vary poor documentation on either LabelSources or LabelWorkspace (whats the difference?).

Here's what I currently have:

`<mtbwa:LabelSources 
        Child="[LabelChildOption.Replace]" 
        Comment="Published to Container" 
        DisplayName="Create Container Label" 
        sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="LabelSources_1" 
        Items="[{&quot;$/Foo/LabelTest/Sandbox/&quot;}]" 
        Name="[String.Format(&quot;{0}-{1}&quot;, LabelName, Version_Container)]" 
        Recursion="[RecursionType.Full]" 
        Scope="$/Foo" 
        mva:VisualBasic.Settings="Assembly references and imported namespaces serialized as XML namespaces" 
        Version="T" />`

It definitely hits the action, but no labels can be found after the fact.

Any help would be much appreciated. and Any tangible documentation, other than Class Documentation with sparse definitions would also be greatly appreciated

Edit 1: Tried to clear up my goal.

Comment: can i clarify, when you say " I want to create a Label, and add all the files in the compiled project to that label" - this means the source files i.e. uncompiled?  so you want to have a flag and add source files to a label if the flag is set, you then want to update the Source files contained within this label with newer versions if the flag was again set?  is that correct?

Comment: Labels are effectively tags on source file(s). You don't add source files to a label, you apply the label to a version of the source files. This also means that if you update the source files the label will still point to the older version unless you delete the label and then re-apply it to the newer version.

Comment: From memory (so I might be wrong), LabelSources will apply a label to files that match the criteria (using Items, Version and Scope). LabelWorkspace will label files using the current workspace version.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is built into the existing template. There should be an option in the process definition that refers to Clean Sources which will be set to True.

This option controls wither the build sources get cleaned, deleted and start afresh. Or if a differential is done.

If you have a lot of source code you can set clean sources to false and save a bunch of time getting the code.

You can also speed the build by placing a TFS Proxy on the build box which will cache the files and make a clean build quicker.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your answer was completely missing the point, as the title says, I'm worried about labels, I've edited the sentence that I believe sent you astray to the question at hand.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Most of the built-in activities are poorly-documented for a reason - their only well-tested use case is their use inside TFS' built-in templates (`DefaultTemplate.11.0.xaml`, etc.). I'm afraid you're going to have to write some custom code, in the form of a custom activity, powershell script or something, to achieve other goals.

That said, I don't really understand the process you're trying to set up. Do you just want to have a label set as your latest-successfully-built sources? Why not use the one created automatically by the build itself?

Comment: We have an abnormal deployment structure. We have continuous integration build after very checkin, we have a flag in our build script, that can be set (for a manual build) to publish after its build to different locations. the goal, is when the flag is set, to create a label identifying the codebase, and destination of the published build.